# Viewing large set of polygons in PostGIS using OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, postgresql, php, geophp

I am prety new to GIS. I have set up a postgis database with al large dataset and a openlayers front-end to display it. But since the dataset is getting prety big I am looking for a way to only load the polygons that are currently visible. Currently I am looking at PHP mapscript. Is it posible to achieve wat I want with this or do i need mapserver or something else for this?

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you asking about displaying polygons as vectors, or a raster representation via a wms? I see you have accepted an answer about the second, but I thought you were asking about the first.

Comment: I prefer the first option ( keeping the polygons ) But I haven’t found a solution to do this without loading everything at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are looking for is an [OpenLayers strategy](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/Cluster-js.html). You do not use this directly, but one of the subclasses, such as `BBOX` or `Cluster` or `Fixed`. The cluster strategy does as it says and combines point that are close together into clusters, based on a threshold, which will lead to much faster rendering times when you have many points in view. Unfortunately, the [OpenLayers 2 cluster example](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/strategy-cluster.html) appears to be broken, but if you look at the source code, it will still explain what is going on. In your case, though, the BBOX strategy might be more appropriate, if you only want to request visible polygons.

**EDIT:** Following comments from OP. If the polygons are extremely complex, but you still wish to interact with them client side, you can use [ST_Simplify](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Simplify.html) on the server to reduce their complexity. You can often achieve a reduction in points of 70%+ without any noticeable degradation of the geometry, by playing with the tolerance. Clearly, the geometry is degraded, but depending on the application, this might be acceptable for performance reasons.

Comment: This is not what I am currently looking for, because when I zoom in, all the results are still being rendered even if they are outside of the current view, making the application slow. 
but nevertheless very useful for some other problems I was facing. So thank you!

Comment: Have you tried the BBOX strategy?

Comment: I have tried the BBOX strategy now, it works very nice. But I'm afraid the polygons I need to load are just too heavy

Comment: You could also try [ST_Simplify](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Simplify.html) if you still want the actual vectors client side, though obviously they will not be 100% exact, but you can often reduce them by 70-80% without any obvious visual change.

Comment: I love you! I have used ST_Simplify in combination with Bbox to reduce the quality of the polygon's depending on the zoom level. It works like a charm now!

Comment: It isn't often anyone says that to me :-). I have updated the question, just for completeness. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach is to go with Mapserver or Geosever (since you are new, Geoserver will look a lot easier)
Once you set a WMS service with geoserver, you can add the resulting WMS to your OpenLayers project. 
Geoserver automatically returns only the information in the extent of the current view, also you can set the range of visible scales on your WMS.

Hope this helps.
Leonardo.